Can't install Aubio inside embedded python to use in Unity Windows 11
I am trying to use Aubio inside Unity (I am trying to follow this tutorial)
but I got an error message.
I followed this instruction and I type this command in cmd: .\Scripts\pip.exe install aubio but I got this error
Collecting aubio
  Using cached aubio-0.4.9.tar.gz (479 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\tonno\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nae__h7q\aubio_d64e5b80e34e4946baa180420af258fd\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
          from moresetuptools import build_ext, CleanGenerated
        File "python\lib\moresetuptools.py", line 7, in <module>
          from this_version import get_aubio_version
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'this_version'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I use this Python version (3.8.0 for amd64 from python.org)

This looks like a packaging bug but I could not quickly find anything similar in their issue tracker. https://github.com/aubio/aubio/issues/385 reports a different problem on Windows and has a suggestion to try to install the latest version from Github, but maybe that's challenging if you are a beginner. If Windows is poorly supported, maybe try on Linux?

I have to create a virtual environment and install Aubio from there. Copy the file to the Unity project folder. Follow this tutorial to step 6. Then use this script
using UnityEngine;
using Python.Runtime;
using System;

public class useAubio : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string venvPath = "Path/to/a/virtual/environment";

    void Start(){
        Runtime.PythonDLL = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/python-(Python's version)-embed-amd64/pythonxx.dll";
        PythonEngine.Initialize();
        
        using (Py.GIL())
        {
            //Add the virtual environment's site-packages to sys.path
            dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");
            sys.path.append(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/python-(Python's version)-embed-amd64");
            sys.path.append(venvPath + "/Lib/site-packages");

            // Import the module and print its version
            dynamic myaubio = Py.Import("aubio");

            try
            {
                dynamic version = myaubio.version;
                Debug.Log(version.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Error accessing aubio version: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        // Shutdown the Python engine on application exit
        PythonEngine.Shutdown();
    }
}

